# Azure Event Hubs: Why do I see that the number of outgoing messages more than 10 times the number of incoming messages?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Event Hubs Java SDK.
I am observing a strange issue since last two weeks.
**I see that the number of outgoing messages from the Event Hubs is 20 Times the number of incoming messages.**

I don't see any errors related to checkpointing. I am using spring boot JAVA applications for sending messages to event hub and reading from event hubs. I have fixed number of instances of the application for producer and consumer side. THis means there is no possiblity of scale out or scale in.

Is it possible that this could be due to the version of the Azure event hubs Java SDK library? I am using version 0.15.1. Is this a known issue with event hubs JAVA SDK?

Comment: By any chance did you find a reason for this?

Comment: We did some study and found a few things that could help here. The short answer is that the Java Event hubs SDK does have some bugs that can result in this behavior. We upgraded the SDK.  I would like to stay away from the Event Processor Host JAVA SDK. Now considering using direct recievers.